# non visible fragments going through onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an xml layout that is defined as a root `LinearLayout` that holds 3 fragments in it.

while debugging I noticed that `onResume` is being called even on fragments that are not visible.

is it possible that `onResume` is being called on all fragments in the layout once `setContentView` is set and the `Activity.onResume` is called?

I take this suspicion from the [fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) specifically on the auto layout for large screens